How can I ensure proper alignment of messages in my Flutter chat app?
[in the image you see that two  uses  how there messages are]
1I'm encountering a problem in my Flutter (Dart) code for a chat group I'm building. The issue arises in the chat screen where, upon testing, all messages appear on the right side, even when sent by different users.
How can I ensure proper alignment of messages in my Flutter chat app, where messages sent by different users appear on the correct side of the screen, and include relevant user information such as sender name and timestamp?
I've included the relevant code snippets below. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!




String formatTime(DateTime time) {
  return DateFormat('HH:mm').format(time);
}

class Message {
  final String id;
  final String content;
  final String senderId;
  final String senderName;
  final DateTime timestamp;
  final String appogee;
  final String cne;

  Message({
    required this.id,
    required this.content,
    required this.senderId,
    required this.senderName,
    required this.timestamp,
    required this.appogee,
    required this.cne,
  });
}

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final Message message;
  final bool isSentByCurrentUser;
  final VoidCallback onDeletePressed;
  final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId;
  final Key? key;

  const MessageBubble({
    this.key,
    required this.message,
    required this.isSentByCurrentUser,
    required this.onDeletePressed,
    required this.chatGroupId,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () => _showMessageOptions(context, message, isSentByCurrentUser, chatGroupId),
      child: Align(
        alignment: isSentByCurrentUser ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight,
        child: _messageBubble(message, context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _messageBubble(Message message, BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: isSentByCurrentUser ? MainAxisAlignment.start : MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        if (!isSentByCurrentUser) ...[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              message.senderName,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                color: Colors.grey[600],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(message.content.contains('https://') ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .03 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .04),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .04, vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .01),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: isSentByCurrentUser ?  Colors.blueGrey : const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 43, 48),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(isSentByCurrentUser ? 0 : 30),
                topRight: Radius.circular(isSentByCurrentUser ? 30 : 0),
                bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(30),
                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(30),
              ),
            ),
            child: !message.content.contains('https://')
                ? Text(
                    message.content,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: isSentByCurrentUser ? Colors.black : Colors.white),
                  )
                : ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    child: Image.network(
                      message.content,
                      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                        return Icon(Icons.image, size: 70, color: isSentByCurrentUser ? Colors.black87 : Colors.white);
                      },
                      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                        if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes! : null,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _showMessageOptions(BuildContext context, Message message, bool isSentByCurrentUser, List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Message Options'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Content: ${message.content}'),
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
              Text('Sender: ${message.senderName}'),
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
              Text('Timestamp: ${message.timestamp}'),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            if (isSentByCurrentUser)
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  _showMessageUpdateDialog(context, message, isSentByCurrentUser, chatGroupId);
                },
                child: const Text('Update'),
              ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                _deleteMessage(message.id, chatGroupId);
              },
              child: const Text('Delete'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('Close'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _showMessageUpdateDialog(BuildContext context, Message message, bool isSentByCurrentUser, List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId) {
    String updatedMsg = message.content;

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.message,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 28,
            ),
            Text(' Update Message')
          ],
        ),
        content: TextFormField(
          initialValue: updatedMsg,
          maxLines: null,
          onChanged: (value) => updatedMsg = value,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Text(
              'Cancel',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              _updateMessage(updatedMsg, message.id, chatGroupId);
            },
            child: const Text(
              'Update',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _updateMessage(String updatedMsg, String messageId, List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('EST-groupes')
      .doc(chatGroupId.isNotEmpty ? chatGroupId[0].id : null)
      .collection('messages')
      .doc(messageId)
      .update({
        'content': updatedMsg,
      }).then((_) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Message updated successfully');
        }
      }).catchError((error) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Failed to update message: $error');
        }
      });
  }

  void _deleteMessage(String messageId, List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('EST-groupes')
      .doc(chatGroupId.isNotEmpty ? chatGroupId[0].id : null)
      .collection('messages')
      .doc(messageId)
      .delete()
      .then((_) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Message deleted successfully');
        }
      })
      .catchError((error) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Failed to delete message: $error');
        }
      });
  }
}

class CommunicationGroupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String cne;
  final String appogee;
  final String filiere;
  final int anneeScolaire;
  final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> chatGroupId;
  final String senderName;

  const CommunicationGroupPage({
    required this.cne,
    required this.appogee,
    required this.filiere,
    required this.anneeScolaire,
    required this.chatGroupId,
    required this.senderName,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  _CommunicationGroupPageState createState() => _CommunicationGroupPageState();
}

class _CommunicationGroupPageState extends State<CommunicationGroupPage> {
  final TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isSendingMessage = false;
  late FlutterSoundRecorder _audioRecorder;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _audioRecorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Communication Group'),
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 152, 0),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'lib/images/pattdark.png',
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: _buildChatInterface(context),
              ),
              _buildChatInput(context),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildChatInterface(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _getChatMessagesStream(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
          return const Center(child: Text('Say Hi! '));
        }

        final List<Message> messages = snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
          final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Message(
            id: doc.id,
            content: data['content'] ?? '',
            senderId: data['sender'] ?? '',
            senderName: data['senderName'] ?? '',
            timestamp: (data['timestamp'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
            appogee: data['appogee'] ?? '',
            cne: data['cne'] ?? '',
          );
        }).toList();

        messages.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp.compareTo(b.timestamp));
        return ListView.builder(
          reverse: false,
          itemCount: messages.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final message = messages[index];
            final isSentByCurrentUser = message.senderId == widget.cne;
            return MessageBubble(
              message: message,
              isSentByCurrentUser: isSentByCurrentUser,
              onDeletePressed: () => _deleteMessage(message.id),
              chatGroupId: widget.chatGroupId,
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _getChatMessagesStream() {
    if (widget.chatGroupId.isEmpty) {
      return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('EST-groupes').doc().collection('messages').orderBy('timestamp').snapshots();
    } else {
      return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('EST-groupes').doc(widget.chatGroupId[0].id).collection('messages').orderBy('timestamp').snapshots();
    }
  }

  Widget _buildChatInput(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: Colors.grey[200],
      child: Row(
        children: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => EmojiPicker(
                  onEmojiSelected: (category, emoji) {
                    _messageController.text += emoji.emoji;
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTapDown: (_) {
                _startRecordingVoiceMessage();
              },
              onTapUp: (_) {
                _stopRecordingVoiceMessage();
              },
              onTapCancel: () {
                _stopRecordingVoiceMessage();
              },
              child: TextField(
                controller: _messageController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type your message...',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _isSendingMessage = true;
                  });
                },
                onChanged: (text) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isSendingMessage = text.isNotEmpty;
                  });
                },
                onSubmitted: (_) {
                  if (_isSendingMessage) {
                    _sendMessage(context);
                  } else {
                    _startRecordingVoiceMessage();
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
              if (result != null) {
                PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
                _sendFileMessage(context, file);
              }
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.attach_file),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _sendMessage(context);
              _messageController.clear();
            },
            icon: _isSendingMessage ? const Icon(Icons.send) : const Icon(Icons.mic),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _startRecordingVoiceMessage() async {
    try {
      await _audioRecorder.openRecorder();
      await _audioRecorder.startRecorder(toFile: 'path_to_save_recording');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error starting recording: $e');
    }
  }

  void _stopRecordingVoiceMessage() async {
    try {
      await _audioRecorder.stopRecorder();
      await _audioRecorder.closeRecorder();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error stopping recording: $e');
    }
  }

  void _sendFileMessage(BuildContext context, PlatformFile file) {
    String senderName = widget.senderName;

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('File selected: ${file.name}');
    }
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('EST-groupes')
        .doc(widget.chatGroupId.isNotEmpty ? widget.chatGroupId[0].id : null)
        .collection('messages')
        .add({
      'content': 'File selected: ${file.name}',
      'sender': senderName,
      'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
    });
  }

  void _sendMessage(BuildContext context) async {
    String messageText = _messageController.text.trim();
    if (messageText.isNotEmpty) {
      String senderName = widget.senderName;
      try {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('EST-groupes')
            .doc(widget.chatGroupId.isNotEmpty ? widget.chatGroupId[0].id : null)
            .collection('messages')
            .add({
          'content': messageText,
          'sender': senderName,
          'senderName': senderName,
          'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
        });
        _messageController.clear();
      } catch (e) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Failed to send message: $e');
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _deleteMessage(String messageId) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('EST-groupes')
          .doc(widget.chatGroupId.isNotEmpty ? widget.chatGroupId[0].id : null)
          .collection('messages')
          .doc(messageId)
          .delete();
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Failed to delete message: $e');
      }
    }
  }
}


please provide a snip of your current output too

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

I did add a photo of my interface , do I should  to add the terminal output  . Because  in the debugging  it seems  that there is no error  @Aiman
